# select option ng-repeat not updated after model changed

Tags: angularjs

I have the following html for drop down.

```
<select id="selection">
<option value="{{n}}" ng-repeat="n in selections">{{n}}</option>
</select>
```

where selections is an array of `strings` and the array lives in my `angularJS` controller.
The initial data for the select options are correct, but When the array is updated by getting assigned as `[]` and then pushed in some new data, the select options does not update accordingly.

Are there workarounds for this?

Comment: when u change the array, it is not updating?

Comment: are you `push` ing data by either jQuery or javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sample controller:
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.items = [
     { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
     { id: 2, name: 'bar' },
     { id: 3, name: 'blah' }
   ];
});

html - 
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items"></select>
```

use ng-options instead of ng-repeat.

Comment: How do I specify the `value` for each option using ng-options?